# Example of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Is it possible to have an entire function $F:\mathbb{C^{n}}\to\mathbb{C}$ where $n>1$,  with the property that $F(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)=0$ if and only if $z_1=z_2=\dots=z_n=0$?

Comment: What's wrong with $F(z) = z$?

Comment: Ok, ok, $n>1$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  As described at "[zero set of an analytic functio of several complex variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738425/zero-set-of-an-analytic-functio-of-several-complex-variables)", apply Hurwitz's Theorem to the sequence of functions $\{F_k(z_2,z_3, ..., z_n) \mid k \in \Bbb{Z}_{> 0}\}$, where $F_k(x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n) = F(1/k,z_2,z_3, ..., z_n)
$ and get additional zeroes arbitrarily close to the origin.  So *no* zero of $F$ is isolated.

(I think I recall that the level sets in this setting are $\Bbb{C}$-manifolds of ($\Bbb{C}$-)codimension $1$, but that memory is fuzzy enough that I wouldn't quote me.)

Comment: The zero set doesn't have to be a manifold (it may be non-smooth), but it's a variety of codimension 1.

Comment: @mrf : Thanks for that!  I'm sharpening that memory now...