# Single prescribed zero of a complex multivariate polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Given a point $x\in\mathbb C^n$, can we construct a polynomial in $n$ variables that vanishes solely on that point?

If not, assume $x$ is inside the unit ball, can we prescribe a polynomial in $n$ variables such that $x$ is its only root inside the unit ball?

If not, same question, replacing the unit ball with the unit hypersphere.

Comment: Zeros of analytic functions of several complex variables are not isolated. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738425/zero-set-of-an-analytic-functio-of-several-complex-variables

Comment: thanks, interesting. still it doesn't rule out the hypersphere case

Comment: If it's the only root inside the unit ball, it's isolated.

Comment: yes but i mean one root on the boundary of the ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is not possible for your first two cases. For the last case, if $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$, you can do it with the function
$$
f(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\sum_i^n z_i \overline{x_i}-1.
$$
Then $f(x)=0$ and for any other $z$ in the unit hypersphere, if $z\neq -x$, then the magnitude of the sum is strictly less than $1$ so is not a zero using the fact that Cauchy-Schwarz is strict when not a scalar multiple, and clearly $-z$ is not a root. Intuitively, the zero set is a complex hyperplane that is tangent to the hypersphere at $x$.